# Firestore: Is this document structure good (in terms of speed and cost) for allowing multi-recipient messages, in a chat app?

Tags: performance, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**EDIT:** This doc structure is not good, and I have a follow up question here: [Firestore chat-app: Is this a valid document structure for multi-recipient messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369877/firestore-chat-app-is-this-a-valid-document-structure-for-multi-recipient-messa)

---

Suppose a chat app has 10 million Firebase users, and hundreds of millions of messages.

I have a Firestore collection containing messages represented as documents in a time-series, and each of these messages may be received and viewed by up to 100 of these users.
Please note, these users are not organized in stable groups, since each message may have a completely different set of users that receive it.

I need to be able to find, very efficiently (in terms of time and cost),
all messages after some specific time, directed to some specific user.

My **first attempt** would be to list the recipient users in a `recipients` array, for example:

```
"dateTime" : 2019-01-24T20:37:28Z
"recipients" : [user1033029, user9273842, user8293413, user6273581]
```

However, that will not allow me to do my queries efficiently.

I was thinking that a better document structure, since Firestore is schemaless,
would be to **make each user a field**. For example:

```
"dateTime" : 2019-01-24T20:37:28Z
"user1033029" : true
"user9273842" : true
"user8293413" : true
"user6273581" : true
```

Then, for example, if I want to know all messages for user 8293413 after 3:00 PM today, I could do it like this:

```
messages.where("user8293413", "==", true).where("dateTime", ">=", "2019-01-24T15:00:00Z")
```

From the documentation I know that Firestore will create indexes for all fields,
so it means it will create indexes for user8293413 in specific.
This means the search will be fast, right? And that the number of reads will be kept to a minimum (one read per message).

However, since I have 10 million users, **Firestore will have to create 10 million indexes**
(assuming all users receive messages).

Is that a problem? Will that many indexes affect performance? How about the storage cost of all these indexes? Is Firebase prepared at all for a large number of indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: 2022-11-28

If you reach the 200 index limitation, you now can reach out to Firebase support and request the number of indexes to be raised. Please include all the necessary details and most importantly, the reason why you would need that. It's not a guarantee, as your request still requires an engineering review, but it's worth giving it a try.

---

> However, since I have 10 million users, Firestore will have to create 10 million indexes (assuming all users receive messages).

There is no way to achieve that. According to the official documentation regarding [Firestore indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes):

> Maximum number of composite indexes for a database: **200**

As you can see, you are limited to 200.

> Is that a problem? Will that many indexes affect performance?

Certainly is. Since you cannot get over the 200 limits, it won't affect performance. If you'll stay below the limit, Firestore guarantees you that your queries will be very fast.

> How about the storage cost of all these indexes?

The only cost for indexes is their storage cost. That's it.

> Is Firebase prepared at all for a large number of indexes?

Not for such a big number.

To solve this problem, I recommend you change the logic of structuring the database since creating that number of indexes is not permitted. For that I recommend you to see a possible [database schema](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3KwKQddPoo&index=3&list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb&t=1s) for a chat app, in which you can simply query the chat messages without the use of so many indexes.

Comment: Based on the docs you listed above I have a third attempt here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369877/firestore-chat-app-is-this-a-valid-document-structure-for-multi-recipient-messa

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write it to you.

Comment: The "rooms" database schema the video is not what we need. Each message may have a totally different set of recipients.

Comment: That was only a possible schema. I understand now.